# Facebook comments - Moderation not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am trying to add comments to my Website.
I have followed basic instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ and comments box appears..

I want to enable Moderation, so followed instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#moderation-setup-instructions but I am not able to get the moderation tool to work.. I expect to see comments appearing at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ or see the moderation link on each page with comments, but neither are happening..

I have included the fb:app_id and og:url and have no issues when viewing on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing and tried including the fb:admins (but the guide above suggests i should not include both)

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for answer for 2 days. In my case problem was with `data-url` attribute. I have publications in multiple languages and I set data-url value without language info, so that comments in other languages be seen in each language. But as I see now facebook does not allow that kind of data-url value. I set that value same as exact url in browser and everything works, also I will suggest adding `og:url` value same as exact url.
Hope this will help somebody!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add og alternate languages meta tag like below

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="ka_GE" />
```

First is the current language (example: domain.com/en/item/1)
Second is the alternate language url (example: domain.com/ka/item/1)

Answer (score 0):

How it worked for me...

---

1º Step - Find your user ID:

On Facebook Interface:

- Click  in the top right of Facebook.
- Select Settings & Privacy, then click Settings.
- Click Apps and Websites in the left menu.
- Click View and edit next to an app or game.
- Scroll down to Learn more. Your user ID is in the paragraph below.

Facebook doc about that: https://www.facebook.com/help/1397933243846983

---

2º Step - Find your APP ID or create one here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/

---

3º Step - Add these tags inside HEAD of your page (NEEDS TO BE IN HEAD ONLY):

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="[YOU FACEBOOK USER ID]"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[YOUR APP ID]" />
```

---

4º Step - Set this script where you want to show the comment box:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=[YOUR APP ID]";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="[URL OF YOUR PAGE]" data-num-posts="5" data-width="815" data-colorscheme="light" data-mobile="false" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```